# Open chrome:// protocols in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that reads bookmarks and allows to open them, but it can't open bookmarks like 'chrome://extensions' or 'chrome://settings'. Local files also not doing anything.

```
window.location = 'chrome://settings'
```

gives an error: "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/"
What permission do i need to do that?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.create

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Tabs permission requeired.

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
    var myNewUrl = 'chrome://settings';
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: myNewUrl});
});
```

Comment: No need for tabs permission and no need for getCurrent: you can simply use chrome.tabs.update({url: 'chrome://settings'})